# Expresiones lógicas en pascal

Tags: bucles, pascal

```
while (dd1 <> dd2) or (mm1 <> mm2) or (aa1 <> aa2) do
```

Cuando pongo este loop en Pascal, solamente compara la primer expresión `(dd1 <> dd2)`, y las otras las pasa por alto, ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! A que te referis con que solo compara la primera? tenes algun ejemplo?

Comment: Cuando dd1 == dd2 pero mm1 <> mm2, por ejemplo, el programa no entra al loop

Comment: Tienes un error conceptual sobre la forma de escribir la proposición condicional, te sugiero que repases las [Leyes de Morgan](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyes_de_De_Morgan). Saludos

Comment: El comportamiento en que se evalúan las expresiones booleanas en Delphi puede variar. Tal y como te han comentado, el compilador puede evaluar la expresión utilizando lo que se llama "corto-circuito". Por ejemplo, si en una expresión como la tuya, el primer elemento ya es TRUE, no seguirá evaluando (porque el resultado final SEGURO que es TRUE).  
Este comportamento se puede cambiar, si te interesa, utilizando la directiva {$B} o desde la configuración del proyecto (Delphi compiler/compiling/Complete boolean evaluation). Tienes más info en la documentación: t.ly/mJyu